# specify a function to be called

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this script for random letter cycling below. I want to call this function to happen at a certain click or frame label, but when I call it with tweenmax, I get a runtime error. Can anyone explain to me how to call this function at certain events. I know this is definitely not best practice but have to try somewhere and here is what I did:

```
var targetWord:String = 'home';
var wordSoFar:String = '';
var possibleCharacters:Array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
var ticksBetweenLetters:int = 15;
var currentTick:int = 0;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);


function eFrame(e:Event):void{
    if(currentTick >= ticksBetweenLetters){
        wordSoFar = targetWord.substr(0, wordSoFar.length + 1);
        currentTick = 0;
        ticksBetweenLetters = int(Math.random() * 15);
        if(wordSoFar == targetWord){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
            home.home_title.field.text = targetWord;
            return;
        }
    }

    home.home_title.field.text = wordSoFar + possibleCharacters[int(Math.random() * possibleCharacters.length)];
    currentTick++;    
}
```

I want the event to start when I place it in here:

```
tl.append(TweenMax.from(home.home_title.field, 1, {onStart:eFrame}));
```

but I get this:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on sncc_fla::website_1/eFrame(). Expected 1, got 0.
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at com.greensock::TweenMax/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TimelineMax/renderTime()
    at com.greensock.core::TweenCore/setTotalTime()
    at com.greensock::TimelineMax/set currentTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite/renderTime()
    at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make your parameter optional:

```
function eFrame(e:Event = null):void {
```

You can do this, because you do not use `e` in your listener function.

Another way would be to give `TweenMax` some parameters for the function call.

```
tl.append(TweenMax.from(home.home_title.field, 1, {onStart:eFrame, onStartParams: [null]}));
```

Comment: thanks that got rid of the error but the function still starts on test. I would like it to start where I have that tweenmax timeline script entered. can you see where I can change anything here?

Comment: Thanks. That seem to get it started. For some reason the function stops at the first letter instead of doing the whole cycle. Maybe there is something in my script I might need to look at and change. Once I find I will post further question, unless anyone see anything.

Comment: Sry, I've concentrated on the runtime error. I'm not quite sure what your code should do.

Comment: Oh sorry it cycles through my word letters to end with the actual word. similar to it seen here - http://www.group94.com/. I think they use OOP to conquer this text effect, but I'm not too familiar with OOP yet. Still learning.